# Adding emoji to input field depending on what emoji got clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have these two functions to add a selected emoji to the input field.

However the first click it doesnt show any emoji's, the second click it shows two emoji's and on the third click it shows four emoji's.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<a id="smiley" title="smiley" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this)" >&#128515;</a>
<a id="sadface" title="sadface" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this)" >&#128530;</a>
```

JQuery:

```
function enableTxt(elem) {
    var id = $(elem).attr("id");

    //Add emoji to chat when clicked with selected id
    $("#" + id).click(function() {

        $('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $("#" + id).html());
    });
}
```

Comment: It's funny that all the answers which uses the `onclick` still gets the ID with `.attr` instead of `elem.id`

Comment: @Huangism: actually my answer doesn't use the id at all, since we don't need it.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard except yours

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting mixed up between inline event handlers and unobtrusive event handlers. Basically every time you run "enableTxt" it sets a new "click" event handler onto the same button. So the first time you click nothing happens because it just creates a handler ready for next time. Then the second time you click it runs "enableTxt" (and thus creates another new handler) *and* the handler which "enableTxt" created the previous time. Then the next time, this effect is doubled, etc etc.

This will work much better:

```
<a id="smiley" title="smiley" href="#" class="emoji" >&#128515;</a>
<a id="sadface" title="sadface" href="#" class="emoji" >&#128530;</a>
```

JS

```
// this wrapper stops the code from declaring the handler until the page has loaded 
// all the elements, otherwise the element we want to bind to might not exist yet

$(function() { 
    $(".emoji").click(function() {
        $('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the most useful to me, explains why it didn't work and binds the click cleanly

Answer (score 3):

You should not use click event inside caller function, it binds click event in every function call so it is increasing, remove click event binding from inside the function

```
function enableTxt(elem) {
     $('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $(elem).html());    
}
```

demo https://jsbin.com/misiwuyena/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I thought the click function was necessary.

Comment: @Sean while this works and it's short but it doesn't mean it's the best/most complete answer. ADyson has the proper way to bind click handlers in jquery and you did tag the question as jquery while gaetanoM has the answer that uses only javascript without jquery. Let's be honest this answer was changed to this after others has posted this. It is your choice to pick the answer, I am just informing you so you can learn more

Comment: @Huangism Thank you for your helpful comment. I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You define this event handler:

```
$("#" + id).click(function() {
```

inside the **enableTxt** function. That means, each time you call the outer function a new event handler is added. Hence your issue.

If you need to have the inline code, i suggest to add the event parameter for future necessities and so, the reduced code is:

```js
function enableTxt(elem) {
    document.querySelector('#usermsg').value += elem.textContent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="smiley" title="smiley" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this, event)" >&#128515;</a>
<a id="sadface" title="sadface" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this, event)" >&#128530;</a>
<input type="text" id="usermsg">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

Each time `enableTxt` is called, it will define a new click handler on the element, that's why it adds multiple emojis.

You should insert the emoji directly, for example:

```
function enableTxt(elem) {
    $('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $(elem).html());
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function enableTxt(elem) {
    $('#usermsg').val($('#usermsg').val() + $(elem).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="smiley" title="smiley" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this)" >&#128515;</a>
<a id="sadface" title="sadface" href="#" onclick="enableTxt(this)" >&#128530;</a>
<input id="usermsg">
```